# Rails 5 unable to complete "belongs_to"

Tags: link-to, belongs-to, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm using Rails 5 after many years. The last version I used was Rails 3.  Somehow I can't get "belongs_to" working anymore. I've read all the suggested threads... but I'm just not getting it.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :campaigns

class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

But if I try to link a campaign to its User...

```
<%= link_to @campaign.user.UName, user_path %> </a></div>
```

I need a way to link a campaign to its user... Maybe I'm just a little rusty... I don't remember having ANY trouble linking, for example, a post's author before.

```
undefined method `UName' for nil:NilClass
```

schema.rb

```
 create_table "campaigns", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "category"
    t.string "artist"
    t.string "backer"
    t.string "update_title"
    t.text "update_desc"
    t.timestamp "update_time"
    t.text "faq"
    t.string "comments"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "goal", limit: 53
    t.string "type"
    t.timestamp "start_date"
    t.timestamp "end_date"
    t.string "video"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

create_table "users", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.boolean "superadmin", default: false, null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "UName"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link_to actually generates an 'a' tag, wrapping it with an 'a' tag is unnecessary. You can use link_to like bellow:

```
<%= link_to @campaign.user.name, @campaign.user %>
```

When you call `@campaign.user`, the user is returning nil.
This could happen for two reasons:

1. There is no relationship between that user and campaign. (Because you set it optional `optional: true`)
2. You couldn't set the relationship between models properly.

If the reason is the second one, I bet it's because of `has_many campaigns` line. As I know, you should use it like `has_many :campaigns` (symbol).

Comment: It's the second one. And it actually is has_many :campaigns in the model.. I just mistyped it above.  Any other reason why it wouldn't be working? (I set it to "optional" because I was getting the same error.)

Comment: It could be about migrations. But before that, try creating a user in the rails console and set it to that campaign. Let's see what error it produces.

Comment: Ah... Even back when I was pretty good with Rails I was pretty bad at the console. Can you run me through the commands to do that (set a user to have a campaign in the console.)

Comment: I do not exactly know your model attributes but you can try something like that: `user = User.create(name: 'mystic cola') | user.campaigns.create(name: 'something')` I use '|' to separate lines.

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
 from (irb):2
and if I do: user = User.create(UName: 'mystical', email: 'mystical@gmail.com', password: 'xxx') | user.campaigns.create(name: 'something')

I get: NoMethodError: undefined method `campaigns' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Also:  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'mystical@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'mystical@gmail.com' LIMIT 1

...it thinks I'm trying to create user id #1 for some strange reason...

Comment: And I can see the titles of "campaigns" under ActiveAdmin when I'm creating a new user... but I see a blank space under "user" when I try to search or create a new campaign. (The blank spaces are actually present to the correct number of users... which is currently 4.)

Comment: Try `user = User.new(UName: 'mystical', email: 'mystical@gmail.com', password: 'xxx') | user.save! | campaign = user.campaigns.new(name: 'something') | campaign.save! `. This must be work if there was no error, so we can follow the issue from there. By the way, you can add your migrations too for better understanding.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `save!' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):3

Comment: Was able to get it to work like this: user = User.new(UName: 'mystically', email: 'mystically@gmail.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password') | user.save |
   (153.6ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
campaign = user.campaigns.new(title: 'Gimmie dat mic fool', description: 'Hip-hop innnovation lab hosted by DJ Sprinkles', category: 'music') | campaign.save
Campaign Create (25.8ms)  INSERT INTO `campaigns` (`title`, `description`, `category`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`)
VALUES ('Gimmie dat mic fool', 'Hip-hop innnovation lab hosted by DJ Sprinkles', 'music', '', '', 5)

Comment: So, I think there is no problem after all. My first guess was right. The specific campaign that you show in your view has not belonged to a user. You can try to use link_to_if or something like `<%= @campaign.user ?  link_to(@campaign.user.UName, user_path) : '' %>`

Comment: What I had to do was change my campaign creation from this: campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)) to THIS: def create
      user = current_user
      campaign = user.campaigns.create(campaign_params)

Comment: ...which is what you told me.  So just put that in your answer and I'll put the wrong way I was doing it in the question and I'll accept your answer. (Just in case someone comes up with the same problem.)

Comment: Thanks then. I'm happy to help!